# FluentValidation valide type

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

How I can validate that:

```
[Fact]
public void ValidateLengthRuleSet_NipLengthIsLessThanTen_IsValidShouldBeFalse()
{
    // Arrange
    string nip = "12345";

    // Act
    var result = _validator.Validate(nip, AddMerchantValidatorRuleSet.NIP.ToString());

    // Assert
    result.IsValid.Should().BeFalse();
}

public class NIPValidator : AbstractValidator<string>
{
    public NIPValidator()
    {
        RuleSet(nameof(AddMerchantValidatorRuleSet.NIP), () =>
        {
            RuleFor(nip => nip.ToString()).Length(10);
        });
    }
}
```

Inside the RuleFor I need to access the T, TProperty. But I want to make validator for strings.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It's not [explicitly supported](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/184) by the FluentValidation team as of the 4th January 2016, but there's a way around this:

```
public class NIPValidator : AbstractValidator<string>
{
    public NIPValidator()
    {
        RuleSet(nameof(AddMerchantValidatorRuleSet.NIP), () =>
        {
            RuleFor(nip => nip).Length(10);
        });
    }
}
```

Your test would also not work because you have to specify the optional parameter name on the `validate` method invocation, like so:

```
var result = validator.Validate(nip, ruleSet: nameof(AddMerchantValidatorRuleSet.NIP));
```